# Select statement low performance on simple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, indexing

Using Management Studio, I have a table with the six following columns on my SQL Server:

```
FileID - int 
File_GUID - nvarchar(258)
File_Parent_GUID - nvarchar (258)
File Extension nvarchar(50)
File Name nvarchar(100)
File Path nvarchar(400)
```

It has a primary key on FileID.

This table has around 200M rows. 
If I try and process the full data, I receive an memory error.
So I have decided to load this in partitions, using a select statement in every 20M where I split on the FileID number.

These selects take forever, the retrieval of rows is extremely slow, I have no idea why.. There are no calculations whatsoever, just a pull of data using a SELECT.

When I ran the query analyzer I see:

```
Select cost = 0%
Clustered Index Cost = 100%
```

Do you guys have any idea on why this could be happening or maybe some tips that I can apply ?

**My query:
Select * FROM Dim_TFS_File**

Thank you!!

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: Just did, its a simple select.. nothing more

Comment: Maybe take a look on fragmentation of the index?

Comment: I suspect the time may be either network or client processing time. Try running the query from SSMS with the discard results option (Query-->Query Options-->Results-->Grid-->Discard Results after execution) on the database server and on the client machine. You can do the same with a Powershell script if SSMS isn't available.

Comment: 200 millions of rows will take some time to transfer. Check HD, network etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor the query while it's running to see if it's blocked or waiting on resources. If you can't easily see where the bottleneck is during monitoring the database and client machines, I suggest you run a couple of simple tests to help identify where you should focus your efforts. Ideally, run the tests with no other significant activity and a cold cache.

First, run the query on the database server and discard the results. This can be done from SSMS with the discard results option (Query-->Query Options-->Results-->Grid-->Discard Results after execution). Alternatively, use a Powershell script like the one below:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=Performance Test";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dim_TFS_File;", $connection);
$command.CommandTimeout = 0;
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$connection.Open();
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery(); #this will discard returned results
$connection.Close();
$sw.Stop();
Write-Host "Done. Elapsed time is $($sw.Elapsed.ToString())";
```

Repeat the above test on the client machine. The elapsed time difference reflects data transfer network overhead. If the client machine test is significantly faster than the application, focus you efforts on the app code. Otherwise, take a closer look at database and network. Below are some random notes that might help remediate performance issues.

This trivial query will likely perform a full clustered index scan. The limiting performance factors on the database server will be:

CPU: Throughtput of this single-threaded query will be limited by spead of a single CPU core.

Storage: The SQL Server storage engine will use read-ahead reads during large scans to fetch data asynchronously so that data will already be in memory by the time it is needed by the query. Sequential read performance is important to keep up with the query.

Fragmentation: Fragmentation will result in more disk head movement against spinning media, adding several milliseconds per physical disk IO. This is typically a consideration only for large sequential scans on a single-spindle or low-end local storage arrays, not SSD or enterprise class SAN. Fragmentation can be eliminated with a reorganizing or rebuilding the clustered index. Be sure to specify MAXDOP 1 for rebuilds for maximum benefits.

SQL Server streams results as fast as they can be consumed by the client app but the client may be constrained by network bandwidth and latency. It seems you are returning many GB of data, which will take quite some time. You can reduce bandwidth needs considerably with different data types. For example, assuming the GUID-named columns actually contain GUIDs, using uniqueidentifier instead of nvarchar will save about 80 bytes per row over the netowrk and on disk. Similarly, use varchar instead of nvarchar if you don't actually need Unicode characters to cut data size by half.

Client processing time: The time to process 20M rows by the app code will be limited by CPU and code efficiency (especially memory management). Since you ran out of memory, it seems you are either loading all rows into memory or have a leak. Even without an outright out of memory error, high memory usage can result in paging and greatly slow throughput. Importantly, the database and network performance is moot if the app code can't process rows as fast as data are returned.

Comment: Can you show the Execution Plan of this query? Can you run Sql Profiler with Execution Plan turned on to see locks?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dan!
Super appreciated, will run those tests !